# Size of subset of an array with largest bitwise AND product?

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation

If given an array A consisting of N integers, how can I return the size of the largest possible subset of A such that its AND product is greater than 0???

I've been at this all day and still cant get the desired result.

Are you guys able to see what's wrong with my code?

I am inputting an array of N size = {13,7,2,8,3},
output should be 3, and I get 5...

Any help is appreciated. thanks!!

```j
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int n = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
        int[] a = new int[n];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            a[i] = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());            
        }
        
        int mAND = toBitWise(a);
        
        int maxCombinados = checarMax(a, 0, 0, 0, mAND);
        
        System.out.println(maxCombinados);
    }
    private static int toBitWise(int[] a){
        int nAND = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            nAND &= a[i];        
    }
        return nAND;
    }
        
    public static int checarMax(int[] a, int i, int cAND, int cSize, int mAND){
        
        if(i == a.length){
            if(cAND == mAND){
                return cSize;
            }
            else{
                return a.length;
            }
        }
        
        int prueba = checarMax(a, i + 1, cAND & a[i], cSize + 1, mAND);
        
        int ign = checarMax(a, i + 1, cAND, cSize, mAND);
        
        return Math.max(prueba, ign);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is mostly an algorithm question, isn't it? Hint: there are only 32 bits in an int.

Comment: @serendipitatt You have added a code snippet, please also explain what is the problem you are facing with the code

Comment: @ManishKothari sorry! I added more details now.

Comment: Your `toBitWise` is always going to return 0.

Answer (score 2):

A brute-force solution is to try all 31 permutations of non-empty subsets of that 5-value set.

To iterate the permutations, just iterate the numbers 1-31, and check the 5 bits to see which values from the array to include in the result, i.e. use bit-manipulation to find the permutations, then use bit-manipulation to AND the values of the permutation.

```java
static int findLargestSubset(int... values) {
    if (values.length > 30)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too many values");
    
    // Iterate all subsets (permutations), except the empty subset
    int maxSubsetSize = 0;
    int subsetCount = 1 << values.length;
    for (int subsetMask = 1; subsetMask < subsetCount; subsetMask++) {
        
        // 'AND' all values in the subset
        int result = -1; // all bits set
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            if ((subsetMask & (1 << i)) != 0) // value is in subset
                result &= values[i];
        
        // Check subset size if result is non-zero
        if (result != 0) {
            int subsetSize = Integer.bitCount(subsetMask);
            if (subsetSize > maxSubsetSize)
                maxSubsetSize = subsetSize;
        }
    }
    return maxSubsetSize;
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(findLargestSubset(13,7,2,8,3)); // prints 3
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using bit-manipulation? It's still all a bit confusing to me...

Comment: @serendipitatt Sure, you could use recursion to iterate through all the permutations of subsets. Bit-masking is easier, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
initialize ans = 0
for i in each 31 bits:
  count = 0
  for n each numbers in array:
    check if the ith position of n has 1 -> count++
  ans = max(ans, count)
return ans
```